# How to make a callback function for range topic

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, range, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am subscribing to a range message but am unsure what to do. I need to save the range value as a double into a global array variable. I have:

```
void front(const sensor_msgs::Range &msg)
{
     data[0] = ???;
}
```

I am unsure was goes in the ??? obviously. I think it is something like `msg->range.size()` but I am not sure. Is this correct?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64816/how-to-make-a-callback-function-for-range-topic/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [sensor_msgs/Range.msg](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Range.html), the data is in `msg->range`. The range is a float32 (a single number).

If you were to use the [sensor_msgs/LaserScan.msg](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) instead, the set of ranges would be found in `msg->ranges`. Then `msg->range.size()` would have some meaning (since it's a vector).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-06-11**:
I am using IR sensors. Thanks for your help!